# React 16 - Meteor SSR

Tags: reactjs, meteor, server-side

OK, I'm building a meteor app with React 16 and I need to serve server-side CSV files. I was using Picker for React 15 but for some reason React 16 just keeps redirecting to a hashbang of the route I'm trying to redirect to.

http://localhost:3000/csv/:some_id

redirects to:

http://localhost:3000/csv/:some_id#/

Any help would appreciated

Comment: Show us  the code where the problem happens. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Found a new library that works with React 16 / react-router-dom
https://mhagmajer.github.io/server-router/